# How to create Airflow variables from environment variables

Tags: airflow

https://airflow.apache.org/docs/stable/howto/connection/index.html#creating-a-connection-with-environment-variables

This page says we can create Airflow connections from environment variables.
e.g.

> AIRFLOW_CONN_POSTGRES_MASTER=postgres://user:password@localhost:5432/master

If so, how we can create Airflow variables, which can be created Admin -> Variables on UI?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The environment variable needs to have a prefix of AIRFLOW_CONN_ for Airflow with the value in a URI format to use the connection properly.

When referencing the connection in the Airflow pipeline, the conn_id should be the name of the variable without the prefix.

For example, if the conn_id is named postgres_master the environment variable should be named AIRFLOW_CONN_POSTGRES_MASTER (note that the environment variable must be all uppercase).

Airflow assumes the value returned from the environment variable to be in a URI format 
(e.g.`postgres://user:password@localhost:5432/master` or s3://accesskey:secretkey@S3).

The underscore character is not allowed in the scheme part of URI, so it must be changed to a hyphen character (e.g. google-compute-platform if conn_type is google_compute_platform). Query parameters are parsed to one-dimensional dict and then used to fill extra.
Connection Types

https://airflow.apache.org/docs/stable/howto/connection/index.html

Comment: Thanks but use of environment variable would be better since it can easily create on Docker environment.

Answer (score 1):

Since airflow 1.10.10, variables can be stored as environment variables using this convention:

AIRFLOW_VAR_<variable_name>

You can use the variables in DAGs, but they won't be visible in the UI.

Source: https://airflow.apache.org/docs/stable/concepts.html#storing-variables-in-environment-variables